# Parametrized complex string working with gpkg in python

Tags: python, string, backslash

I need to construct a chain of text like this:

```
 out = 'ogr:dbname=\'C:\\output\\2020.gpkg\' table=\"2020\" (geom) sql='
```

Here is my code:

```
import glob, time, sys, threading, os
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime
import time, threading

#Parameters
layer = 'C:\\layer.gpkg' 
n ='2020'
outdir = 'C:\\output'

#Process
l = os.path.realpath(layer)
pn = os.path.realpath(outdir + '/' + n + '.gpkg')
p = f"'{pn}'"
f = f"'{n}'"
o = f'ogr:dbname={p} table={f} (geom) sql='

#Test
out = 'ogr:dbname=\'C:\\output\\2020.gpkg\' table=\"2020\" (geom) sql='
o == out
```

The goal is to get o == out.

What do I need to change in the #Process part in order to get this as True ?

Moreover I need to run this either in linux or windows.

My final goal is to create a function that give 3 strings returns the complex string line shown above.

Comment: "I don't even understand why the output changes single quotes to double quotes." _Inside_ a string this matters. But if you're talking about the quotes defining the string itself this is irrelevant. Try `'foo' == "foo"`.

Comment: There's no difference between single quote and double quote for defining a string in python. But using them in mixed mode can save you some backslashes sometimes. You need string formatting. A simple example with `f` string. `f"org:dbname='{trypath}'"`.

Comment: Are you sure the string you're trying to generate should escape both single _and_ double quotes? Do you want those backslashes to actually be contained in the final string?

Comment: Going to the point I need to solve the \'/ part. \ must come from one string and '/path' from another.

Comment: Try outputlayer = '\'ogr:dbname=\\' + '\'' + trypath + '\''

Comment: Sorry but doesn't work. This is the result of that: "'ogr:dbname=\\'/dir1/dir2.gpkg'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one of the issues that this isn't working is your path here `pn = os.path.realpath(outdir + '/' + n + '.gpkg')`. This is trying to combine UNIX path `/` with windows path `\\`. A more robust solution in terms of portability between linux and windows would be to use the `path.join` function in os module.

Additionally, python f strings will only add escapes to whichever quote character you used to open the string (`'` or `"`). If the escaped quotes around both strings are necessary, you're probably better off hard coding it into an f-string instead of setting 2 new variables with different quote types.

```
import glob, time, sys, threading, os
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime
import time, threading

#Parameters
layer = 'C:\\layer.gpkg' 
n ='2020'
outdir = 'C:\\output'

#Process
l = os.path.realpath(layer)
pn = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(outdir, f"{n}.gpkg"))
o = f'ogr:dbname=\'{pn}\' table=\"{n}\" (geom) sql='

#Test
out = 'ogr:dbname=\'C:\\output\\2020.gpkg\' table=\"2020\" (geom) sql='
o == out
```

A version of this (different path) has been tested to work on my linux machine.

Comment: Sorry for asking you this but, in case you downvote the question, could you please almost remove that downvote ? My profile is blocked for 6 months and I need to ask a question. This is my only question with negative rate. I think this blocked me. Regards.

Comment: I didn't downvote, I'm a believer in learning through discussion. Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using python 3.6 or above you should use format strings (also known as f strings) to construct strings from variables. Start the string with the letter "f" and then put whatever variables you want in curly brackets {}. Also if you use single quotes as the outer quote then you don't have to escape double quotes and vice versa.

Code:

```py
db_name = "'home/user/output/prueba.gpkg'"
table_name = '"prueba"'
outputlayer = f'ogr:dbname={db_name} table={table_name} (geom) sql='
outputlayer
```

Output:

```
'ogr:dbname=\'home/user/output/prueba.gpkg\' table="prueba" (geom) sql='
```

Comment: Sorry for asking you this but, in case you downvote the question, could you please almost remove that downvote ? My profile is blocked for 6 months and I need to ask a question. This is my only question with negative rate. I think this blocked me. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a triple quoted string:

```
dbname = """/home/user/output/prueba.gpkg"""
outputlayer = """ogr:dbname='"""+dbname+"""' table="prueba" (geom) sql="""
```

which gives:

```
'ogr:dbname=\'/home/user/output/prueba.gpkg\' table="prueba" (geom) sql='
```

Comment: Thanks but the directory must be inserted as parameter.

Comment: Sorry for asking you this but, in case you downvote the question, could you please almost remove that downvote ? My profile is blocked for 6 months and I need to ask a question. This is my only question with negative rate. I think this blocked me. Regards.

Comment: It wasn't me who down voted, but you should have been informed as to why you were banned